# Were the charges listed by Walsh legitimate?

Tags: realism, midnight-run

On the flight to Las Vegas in *Midnight Run*, Walsh describes a list of charges the feds can apply to Serrano:

> **Perry:**  There are no real computer disks. Is that right?
>   **Walsh:**  Right.
>   **Perry:**  If you give him blank disks and he accepts them, is that an overt act?
>   **Walsh:**  If he just sets foot inside the airport, he's committed an overt act: conspiracy to obstruct justice. When he shows up with the Duke, you add kidnapping. Anybody packing a gun: conspiracy to commit murder. The fact it's an airport, and Alonzo, correct me if you think I'm wrong...you can slap an interstate transportation racketeering rap on him.
>   **Mosely:** None of that means anything unless you can get him to take those disks.
>   **Walsh:**  Don't worry. I'll get him to take the disks.
>   **Mosely:** Get a wire on this man.

Would those charges listed hold up in the court of law?

Comment: A fine cinematic choice.

Comment: You might try https://law.stackexchange.com/ for those who would know.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I debated that.  Thought I would try here first.  Didn't want to double-post.

Comment: @LarsTech I posted a question on the Law StackExchange site one time and got 4 downvotes within an hour. They're pretty critical about questions over there!

Answer (score -1):

> Would those charges listed hold up in the court of law?

Note that "hold up in court" doesn't mean that they lead to a conviction; but rather that the charges are not dismissed by the judge before trying the suspect. What Walsh is saying here is that the particular actions (e.g. bringing a gun) open the door to having a valid claim as to particular crime (conspiracy to commit murder) having taken place.

So yes, Walsh is indirectly stating that if these boxes are ticked, the charges will hold up in court (even if the defendant is not actually found guilty of them).

I am not a lawyer but the listed items make sense, and there's nothing in the script that suggests that Walsh was either lying or mistaken.